# How to load faster Parent Activity from Child Activity?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-activity, android-logcat

actionBar.setHome function calls Application Home Activity. When it is calling, it's just like re-opening the app. I mean I have to wait to load Home Activity. I think there may be a way not to re-load, re-load Home Activity but to Home Activity hidden or store memory for Home Activity. Home Activity has font embedded,two tabs and buttons. When a button from Home Activity, the activity goes to another activity in which actionBar.setHome function redirect Home Activity just like re-loading it. 

**Child Activity code:**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.......................
.......................
actionBar.setHomeAction(new IntentAction(this, createIntent(this),
            R.drawable.ic_title_home_default));
  }
  //calling Parent Activity
   private static Intent createIntent(Context context) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, CustomTabActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    return i;
  }
```

**Logcat after calling Home Activity from another activity:**

```
04-14 22:20:49.788: I/ActivityManager(245): Starting: Intent { flg=0x4000000 cmp=com.joshclemm.android.tabswithactivity/.CustomTabActivity } from pid 30761
04-14 22:20:49.838: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:49.898: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:49.908: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:49.918: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:49.928: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:49.938: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:49.958: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:49.968: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:49.978: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:49.988: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.008: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.018: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.028: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.038: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.048: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.068: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.078: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.088: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.098: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.118: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.128: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.138: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.148: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.158: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.178: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.188: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.198: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.208: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.228: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.238: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.248: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.258: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.268: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.288: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.298: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.308: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.318: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.338: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.348: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.568: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.648: D/szipinf(30761): Initializing inflate state
04-14 22:20:50.678: D/skia(30761): purging 191K from font cache [28 entries]
04-14 22:20:50.718: D/skia(30761): purging 192K from font cache [27 entries]
04-14 22:20:50.978: I/ActivityManager(245): Displayed com.joshclemm.android.tabswithactivity/.CustomTabActivity: +1s172ms
```

What additional codes are needed in Home Activity Class-> OnCreate() or whatever method not to try re-load if once already loaded? 
Or how to let Home Activity hidden if the function calls another activity?

Answer (score 0):

Shit I solve my questions myself. Whatever thank you all viewers of this questions.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.......................
.......................
actionBar.setHomeAction(new IntentAction(this, createIntent(this),
            R.drawable.ic_title_home_default));
  }
  //calling Parent Activity
   private static Intent createIntent(Context context) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, CustomTabActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    return i;
  }
```

Change is: FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT